# Conclude $u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Lambda)$ for all $u,v\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$ from the Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\left\{2,3\right\}$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $u,v\in H_0^1(\Lambda)$
- $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,d\right\}$

> I want that $$u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Lambda)\tag 1\;.$$ Which further assumption on $\Lambda$ do I need?

By *Hölder's inequality*, $$\left\|u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda)}\le\left\|\left|u\right|^2\right\|_{L^p(\Lambda)}\left\|\left|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right|^2\right\|_{L^q(\Lambda)}\tag 2$$ for all $p,q\in[1,\infty]$ with $1/p+1/q=1/2$ and hence (for $p=q=2$) $$\left\|u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda)}\le\left\|u\right\|_{L^4(\Lambda)}\left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\right\|_{L^4(\Lambda)}\tag 3\;.$$

> So, it would be sufficient, if each element of $H_0^1(\Lambda)$ would admit a representative in $W^{1,\:4}(\Lambda)$.

The following is according to [Theorem 5.6.3](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq=%22This+estimate+is+sometimes+called%22+evans&source=bl&ots=dkhcwyTyqN&sig=lfA3UKvrNuDtChbd82kL0kWMBW0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb5uOL1bnOAhUUM8AKHUXUCdEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22This%20estimate%20is%20sometimes%20called%22%20evans&f=false) and [Theorem 5.6.6](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22General+Sobolev+inequalities%22+%22be+a+bounded+open%22&source=bl&ots=dkhcwySspM&sig=c8tmBjV2HLVmKLETJ84liMsfckw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc86iLz7nOAhXGcRQKHX6HD-4Q6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=%22General%20Sobolev%20inequalities%22%20%22be%20a%20bounded%20open%22&f=false) of *Partial Differential Equations* by *Lawrence C. Evans*: If $\Lambda$ is bounded and $d>2$, then $$\left\|w\right\|_{L^6(\Lambda)}\le C_1\left\|\nabla w\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for all }w\in H_0^1(\Lambda)\tag 4$$ for some $C_1\ge 0$. If $\Lambda$ is bounded with $\partial\Lambda\in C^1$ and $d>2$, then $$\left\|w\right\|_{L^6(\Lambda)}\le C_2\left\|u\right\|_{H^1(\Lambda)}\;\;\;\text{for all }w\in H^1(\Lambda)\tag 5$$ for some $C_2\ge 0$.

> However, the corresponding statements for $d=2$ are useless and even in the case $d=3$ I cannot conclude $(1)$ from $(4)$ or $(5)$. So, is there any chance for $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which further assumption on Λ do I need?

You need $\Lambda=\emptyset$.

The statement

> For all $u,v\in H^1_0(\Lambda)$ it holds $u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Lambda)$

will never be true in space dimensions larger than one. The weak derivative $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}$ is only $L^2(\Lambda)$ and not better in general. In order that the claim is true, one would need $u\in L^\infty(\Lambda)$, which does not hold for $d\ge2$.

In order to construct an explicit counterexample, take a function $u\in L^2(\Lambda)\setminus L^4(\Lambda)$ (such functions exist), and define $v(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{x_i} u(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}, s, x_{i+1},\dots,x_d)ds$.

Comment: It should be $\Lambda$ instead of $\Omega$ in your second highlighted statement.

Comment: What about $u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\in L^{\frac43}(\Lambda)$? The question arose because the trilinearform $$b(u,v,w):=\langle w,(u\cdot\nabla)v\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\sum_{i,j=1}^d\int_\Lambda u_i\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}w_j\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }u,v,w\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$$ [occurs in the study of the Navier-Stokes equations](http://tinyurl.com/jhhdxbu) and I've wondered whether the integral is even defined.

Comment: That is true for $d\le 4$: by embedding $u\in L^4(\Lambda)$, so with Hoelder inequality the product $u v_{x_i}$ is in $L^{4/3}(\Lambda)$